# Is it possible that a shared host is really offering unlimited inodes?

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting

I was searching for a hosting service with unlimited inodes and I found one: IPAGE.  But everywhere I read says that there is no hosting with unlimited inodes.  If that is so, then how can Ipage can provide that?  The customer support team is saying that it's unlimited.

[image: CHAT WITH IPAGE TEAM]

Can I trust them, or are there really some limits?

Comment: See also: [How do I work around hitting the inode limit imposed by web hosts?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60664/how-do-i-work-around-hitting-the-inode-limit-imposed-by-web-hosts)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Do web hosts really mean 'Unlimited'?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33284/do-web-hosts-really-mean-unlimited)

Comment: In linux, inodes is a static number. It can be increased of course, however, traditionally, there is no mechanism for doing this dynamically though it is possible. The problem with inodes is the mechanism involved with the indexing of files. Regardless of how the drives are set-up, there is always a performance hit when increasing inodes some of which can be avoided, however, never fully. I trashed a perfectly good hard-drive with too many inodes and found a significant degrade of performance past a certain point. Again, some of this can be avoided, but not fully.

Comment: I suspect this is a case if reaching first line support, asking them a question they haven't got a clue about, and them giving you the answer they think you want to hear in order to make a sale.

Comment: Why are you searching for unlimited *inodes* ? This is surely a consequence of something else so it would help to have your explanation from where do you come to need this.

Answer (score 2):

No.

One host's limit is possibly lower or higher than the other, but there is always a limit. It's a file system after all.